# How to create a DataFrame of more than 700 MB data from SQL Server using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have SQL table with more than 700 MB and keep increasing on daily basis which I have to write to a TXT file and SFTP it.

The below code is going for a time out.

```
for df in pd.read_sql(query, conn, chunksize=1000000)
```

Is there any other way I can chunk the result and send it smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

your code doesn't really make any sense as you're not assigning `pd.read_sql` to anything

try :

```
chunk_size = 50000
dfs = []
for chunk in pd.read_sql("query",con=engine,chunksize=chunk_size)
    #transformation 
    dfs.append(chunk)
```

you can then concat the dataframe(s) and save this to a single txt file with a gzip compression since the dataframe is v.large.

```
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
final_df.to_csv('file.txt.gz',index=False,compression='gzip')
```

Comment: Tried this method. Still timeout when running from server .

Comment: what database are you using, whats handling the connection layer?